# g++ linking .so libraries that may not be compiled yet

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, g++, qmake

Im helping on a c++ application. The application is very large and is spread out between different sub directories.  It uses a script to auto generate qt .pro files for each project directory and uses qmake to then generate make files.  Currently the libraries are being compiled in alphabetical order.. which is obviously causing linking errors when a library its trying to link isn't built yet..  Is there some kind of g++ flag i can set so it wont error out if a library its trying to link hasn't been built yet? or a way to make it build dependencies first through the qt .pro file?

NOTE:
This script works fine on ubuntu 10.10 because the statements to build the shared libraries didnt require that i use -l(libraryname) to link to my other libraries but ubuntu 11.10 does so it was giving me undefined reference errors when compiling on 11.10.

Comment: Sounds like you need a proper Makefile.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't just linking with some previously built libraries in Ubuntu? I don't see how it could successfully link with non-existent library files.

Comment: shouldnt be. the libraries it was giving errors on where libraries generated from our code. clean rebuilding works fine on 10.10. 11.10 was giving me the undefined reference errors.

Comment: Is there some order in which they could all be built, or are there cyclic dependencies?

Comment: There are some libraries that are circular dependent...

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using Qt Creator as a build environment and IDE? I've personally never used it for development on Ubuntu, but I have used it on Windows with g++, and it works great there. And it appears its already available as a [package in the repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qtcreator).

Some of the advantages you get by using it are:

- Qt Creator will (generally) manage the .pro files for you. (If you're like me, you can still add lots of extra stuff here, but it will automatically add .cpp, .h, and .ui files as they are added to the project.)
- You can set up inter-project dependencies that will build projects in whatever order they need to link.
- You can use its integration with gdb to step through and debug code, as well as jump to the code.
- You get autocomplete on Qt signals and slots, as well as inline syntax highlighting and some error checking.
- If you're doing GUIs, you can use the integrated designer to visually layout and design your forms.

Referring back to your actual question, I don't think it's possible for a flag to tell gcc to not error when a link fails simply because there is no way for the linker to lazily link libraries. If its linking to static libraries (.a), then it needs to be able to actually copy the implementation of that code into the executable/library. If its dynamically linking (.so), it still needs to verify that the required functions actually exist in the library. If it can't link it during the linkage step, when can it link?

As a bit of an afterthought, if there are cyclic dependencies in your compile process (A depends on B, B on C, and C on A), then you might need to have a fake version of a library get built first, which only has empty stubs for the implementation of each function, and the full definition for each class or object. Then, build everything else while linking to that, and at the end, build the real version of the fake library, and link it to all the other versions that were already linked. I think this would only work on dynamic linking, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subdirs project to have control over the build order (no matter whether the other dev wants it or not :) ).

E.g.

build_all.pro

```
TEMPLATE=subdirs
CONFIG+=ordered
SUBDIRS=lib2/lib2.pro lib1/lib1.pro app/app.pro
```

The lib1.pro, lib2.pro, ... are your generated pro files.
Then run qmake once for the build_all.pro and also run make in that directory. This will build lib2 before lib1 and then app.